# Timeout in whois command

Tags: linux, timeout, whois

Unable to figure out the problem with whois command. Whenever i give any query to whois command it gives timeout error. I also learned about jwhois command but it seems it is also getting similar problem. I am searching for this but not find anything useful. These are the error given while running the command and i also run whois on many other domain but no success. Please help!

```
knight07@bt:~$ whois google.com
Timeout

knight07@bt:~$ jwhois google.com
[Querying whois.verisign-grs.com]
[Unable to connect to remote host]
```

Comment: A firewall is blocking the whois service?

Comment: I don't think so, i opened port 43 for tcp and udp. But still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you do `strace -vo whois.txt whois www.google.com` (or whatever name) and put the result to pastebin.com?

Comment: I have done `strace -v -T whois www.google.com` http://pastebin.com/HbpibUSj  and i think the error is on line 285 as it is taking almost 60 seconds and then timeout occurs.

Comment: Now compare that with my whois (starting at looking up whois.crsnic.net). The IP address differs, but it works for me. See http://pastebin.com/d9SpCbfb

Comment: Does whois.conf file exist in your system (as you not pasted your complete stracing) and whois accessing it while execution? In my system it does not exist so whois is unable to read it. I think this can be a problem as I read some post where a administrator does not have the whois.conf file and also getting the `Timeout` error. But they are not able to solve that. Is this really a problem? From where can I found whois.conf file?

Comment: There's a description of whois.conf's syntax on https://github.com/weppos/whois-debian/blob/master/src/whois.conf. So you could try a line `\.com$ 199.7.61.74` put into `/etc/whois.conf`. Then do `whois www.google.com`, maybe preceded by `strave -v` again.

Comment: I forgot: can you record the network traffic too? With wireshark or tcpdump, if it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same thing happening and it's almost certainly because one of the central whois servers has blocked you for too many queries.  I suspect it's Verisign's .com server that is being touchy as I can get names lik

I haven't yet found out a way to remove myself from the block list but am working on it and would appreciate hearing anything you find out!

To test this, try a whois of flabbalabbaz.info - you'll get an immediate response; then try a whois of flabbalabbaz.com or .net - you'll time out.

The most usual cause of getting blacklisted is too many queries from some sort of automated system.  We have a whois script built into one of our helpdesk operators' tools, but it doesn't actually issue many requests so I'm rather disappointed they've seen fit to block us for what would only have been a relatively small number of queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error as mentioned in Brian C.'s Answer above, you're probably using a VPN and Verisign is blocking you due to someone on that VPN having abused WHOIS. Turn off your VPN temporarily to make the query or add an exception to your VPN for WHOIS. In my case, using Linux on WSL, I just had to suspend my VPN for a moment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1119212)